# how do i know the least number of pen lifting on semi eulerian graph or eulerian graph using math formula?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, discrete-mathematics

the problem : Is it possible to draw a given graph without lifting pencil from the paper, however I want to know the least number of pencil lifting when the graph is not Eulerian, is there a math formula for that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxG3f.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not involve programming. Possibly better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Number of odd vertices seems to be the key.

Comment: i know the second graph does not have eulerian cycle or even it's not semi eulerian , but my question how many edges do i need to add or remove to make semi eulerian or full eulerian so i can draw without lifting the pen . is there a general formula to know from number of odd and even verticies ? @user58697 , cause i tried to write program for that but it  was very slow that's why i am looking to math formula .

Comment: Sounds like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782285/minimum-number-of-total-paths-in-a-connected-graph

Comment: If there are 2 or less odd vertices, the graph is unicursal, right? If there are more than two, an imaginary edge between them reduces their count by two. Notice that this imaginary edge corresponds to lifting the pen. Keep reducing until you reach 2 or 1.

Comment: "Keep reducing until you reach 2 or 1." One would not be possible due to the Handshaking Lemma, which shows the number of odd-degree vertices is always even.